# Lie Algebras- Understanding the Span of Commutators

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-algebras

Suppose that $V$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{F}$, with $\dim V=n$. Let $H$ and $K$ be subspaces of $V$. Then $[H,K]$ is defined to be the set of all linear combinations of the commutators $[h,k]$ with $h\in H$ and $k\in K$. Or more concisely, $[H,K]=\langle\{[h,k]:h\in H, k\in K\}\rangle$.

---

I am struggling to understand the above definition of $[H,K]$ and make sense of what the elements of $[H,K]$ look like. Rewriting, I think that $$[H,K]=\left\{\sum_{i}\lambda_i[h_i,k_i]:h_i\in H\,, k_i\in K\,, \lambda_i\in\mathbb{F}\right\}\,.$$ But it doesn't seem obvious to me why this sum is finite. The basis of $V$ is finite, but there are infinitely many elements of $V$ (and hence $H$ and $K$).

I guess my questions are: what do the elements of $[H,K]$ look like explicitly and why is the sum of the commutators finite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a question of vector spaces only. The sum is finite by definition. We are taking *finite* linear combinations of the basis elements of $U$, for any subspace $U$ in a vector space $V$. 
Even if $V$ is an infinite-dimensional vector space, linear combinations for subspaces are always **finite** sums by definition. We do not have convergence questions here.

Comment: So do we only sum over $\lambda_i [h_i,k_i]$ where $h_i$ and $k_i$ are basis vectors of $H$ and $K$, respectively?

Comment: Yes, the Lie bracket is bilinear. So we can extend to all of $[L,L]$.